# Which are the gotras amongst which marriages are forbidden?

Tags: marriage, gotra

I don't recall where I watched it, there was once this video in YouTube which said people of certain gotras shouldn't marry. I don't mean people of Vasisth gotra and people of Vasisth gotra, which I know is forbidden. But like people of Vasisth gotra and people of Parashar gotra for example. How true is that?

---

Optionally, may I as of Vasisth gotra marry someone of Parashar gotra with prescribed remedies?

Comment: because Vasishta was grandfather of Parashar, they are equivalent gotras. Just like Vishvamitra and Kaushika gotras don't marry. Any gotras where rishis are blood related, are prohibited for marriage, for the same reason that incest is prohibited.